# Bootstrap Scrollspy IE 9 Issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't get scrollspy to work in IE 9. I reduced the code to the very basic but the issue remains.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #sidenav {
                position: fixed;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            li {
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                background-color: orange;
            }
            li.active {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
            a.active {
                color: red;
            }
            .box {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: red;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            body {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body data-spy="scroll" target="sidenav">
        <div id="sidenav">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#box-1">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#box-2">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#box-3">Test</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#box-4">Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-4"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-5"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-6"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-7"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box-8"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '#sidenav'
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mXn6P/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail the difference in behaviour you see between IE9 and another browser where you see the desired behaviour?

Comment: I've setup a JsFiddle, does it reproduce the problem for you in IE9?

I tested using IE11, setting Document mode to '9', but I don't know how good this is at backwards emulating the older browsers. Certainly when I scrolled up and down the active `<li>` was shown correctly. As well as clicking on it the page jumped to the right anchor.